# Post looped data, then save with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have `textarea` that are generated based on how many times they're in the table for a certain ID. So some people will have no `textarea`, others will have one, others with two, etc... How can I update the tabled based on these using my example if possible.

**Main Page**

```
<?php
$q = $_GET["q"];
$list = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID = ?");
$list->execute(array($q));
$data = $list->fetchAll();
foreach ($data as $row) :?>

<textarea id="TableID<?=$row["TableID"]?>"></textarea>

<?endforeach?>

<div class="button">Save</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( '.button' ).click(function() {
var TableID = $("#TableID").attr('id');
var Comment = $("#TableID").val();

$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "save.php",
data : {
   TableID : TableID,
   Comment : Comment
 }
 });
 });
</script>
```

**Save Page**

```
<?php
 $Comment = $_POST["Comment"];
 $TableID = $_POST["TableID"];

 $save = $db->prepare('UPDATE Table
 SET Comment = ?
 WHERE TableID = ?');
 $save->execute(array($Comment,$TableID));
?>
```

Comment: Add a class to your textareas and select the collection in your jquery form submit. Then post an array with table id indexes. Loop the execute.

Comment: When you UPDATE, are you looking to update a different row in the database for each textarea on your page?  Or do all the textareas with the same 'TableID' need to update the same row?

Comment: @BizzyBob the IDs are all different rows. I don't know how many rows or which rows will show up, it depends on previous input.

Comment: So, is TableID unique for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than generating your `textarea` elements with different numbered names, which would be very cumbersome to process on the back end:

```
<textarea name="TableID1"></textarea>
<textarea name="TableID2"></textarea>
<textarea name="TableID3"></textarea>
```

You can name them so they get placed into a single `$_POST` variable.  To do this, just name them with brackets at the end of the name like this:

```
<textarea name="TableID[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="TableID[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="TableID[]"></textarea>
```

On the PHP side, the values for all 3 of the above text areas would be placed into an array with the values at indexes 0, 1, & 2.

In your case, since you want each textarea to be associated with a specific TableID, use an array within an array using TableID as the first key which would look like this:

```
<textarea name="TableID[12][]"></textarea>
<textarea name="TableID[54][]"></textarea>
<textarea name="TableID[163][]"></textarea>
<textarea name="TableID[180][]"></textarea>
```

In doing this, you'd be passing the TableID as part of the element name, so you don't need to POST 2 different variables, Comment & TableID, you really just need to POST the Comment (textarea value).

So the code in your foreach loop generating the page would look like:

```
<textarea id="Comment[<?=$row["TableID"]?>][]"></textarea>
```

AND your submit code (assuming you wrap your `<textarea>` elements in a `<form>`):

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        $.post('save.php', $('form').serialize(), function () {
            // do something here if you want
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Once you have your data being neatly posted in a single array, just prepare the statement as you are doing already, then wrap the `execute` in a loop that iterates through each TableID:

```
foreach($Comment as $TableID => $CommentText){
    $save->execute(array($CommentText,$TableID));
}
```